# run integration tests with external dependencies. gradle

Tags: jenkins, gradle, testng

I am new to the gradle tool and got next project.

1. TestNG tests with some classes, annotated with @Test.
2. buid.gradle where I got small script.

```
test {
    dependsOn cleanReports
    useTestNG() {
        suites 'src/test/resources/testng.xml'
        systemProperty "property1", System.getProperty("property1")
        systemProperty "property2", System.getProperty("property2")
        systemProperty "property3", System.getProperty("property3")

        listeners << 'listener.BuildReportExecutionListener'
        listeners << 'listener.TestResultListener'
    }
}
```

I want to publish these tests to the artifactory, then In Jenkins use **gradle clean test** on jar file downloaded from artifactory to run specific **release version** of tests.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can build dynamic dependencies that are based on project properties.
https://discuss.gradle.org/t/dynamic-dependency-definitions-using-a-project-property-configuration/22773